# Tomatoes and pepper plants dropping flowers

Tags: tomatoes, plant-recommendations, plant-care, peppers, pollination

I am new to gardening and I have planted tomato and pepper plants. They make flowers but they drop them and they are not making any vegetable.  Any idea what could be reason? I am in the city so I shake plants a bit for pollination like I watched on Internet as we do not have bees.  [image: inmage1]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are your day and night temperatures? Is the soil very often that wet? I don't see many if any dropped blossoms in the pictures. Do you just mean they're not setting fruit?

Comment: ya they not make fruits , they make flowers and after few days drop it , i will calculate temperature of day and night and will update you .. thanks , just one tomato plant made one tomato and one pepper plant made 3 peppers

Answer (score 3):

From the way water stays at the surface it seems that the soil is very compacted. Irregular watering makes your flowers drop, as tomatoes and peppers don't like drought or too much water. I recommend that you water them every day with enough water for 24 hours, trying not to overwater because compacted soil aggravates the problem.

It would be best if you could loosen the soil a bit using a fork, but be careful not to touch the roots. Also, there are too many flowers on each plant and you need to keep only a few of them. There is not enough soil for every flower to become a fruit.

Comment: hmmm ya i water them once a day it morning time , soil is not that hard just that i watered and took photos ,